# Error message - dummy.sh: line 29: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have three environments: test, dev and prod. When the user enters test it should `ftp` to test host and `ftp` the file.
Same in case of dev and prod. I have just tried for test and I am getting the error: `Error message - dummy.sh: line 29: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

```
!/bin/bash
while :
do
read -r INPUT_STRING
case $INPUT_STRING in
        test)
               echo "Please enter id no : "
                                read -r input_variable
                                if [[ ${#input_variable} -ne "7" ]]
                                then
                                echo "Please check the id no given"
                                exit 1
                                fi
                                HOST=xxx
                                USER=xxx
                                PASSWORD=xxx
                                ^Iftp -inv $HOST <<- EOF
                                user $USER $PASSWORD
                                cd /work/path//$input_variable/to/destination/
                                mput x.csv

^IEOF
;;
esac
done
```

Comment: What is the error ?
And where is the ending EOF ?

Comment: Below is the error
dummy.sh: line 28: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Write EOF after `mput x.csv` line

Comment: Yes i have tried and i am getting same error

Comment: **Edit your post to include the error** instead of hiding it in a comment, and change the generic "Can you help please?" to a real question that cannot be answered by just "Yes" or "No"

Comment: Can you explain the use of EOF here ?

Comment: @Anthon - updated now

Comment: Your `while..do` is missing a final `done` at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<<-EOF` instead of `<<EOF` when you want to use indentation. Then indent the text by tabs.

Finally you need to put `EOF` to mark the end of the here-document.

Your code block will be like:

```
    ftp -inv $HOST <<-EOF
            user $USER $PASSWORD
            cd /work/test//$input_variable/path/to destination/
            mput x.csv
    EOF
```

See also http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html, example 19.4 for more information.

Comment: Thanks Lambert..i have changed the code. I am getting the same error..

Comment: @chandraprakash Make sure the word `EOF` is on its own on a line with no spaces around it and **only** tab characters in front of it. To keep it simple, put the word on its own at the start of the line, with no whitespace at all.

Comment: @meuh - below is the change 
^Iftp -inv $HOST <<- EOF
  user $USER $PASSWORD
  cd /work/test//$input_variable/path/to destination/
   mput x.csv
^IEOF
 ;;                              
esac                                
But i am getting the same error

Comment: @chandraprakash you need to [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/280734/edit) your original post with the changes, as it is too hard to read them in a comment

Comment: @meuh - script is updated now. Could you please have a look

Comment: @chandraprakash There should not be a space between `<<-` and `EOF` so: `<<-EOF`. And verify the `^I`. Perhaps is it mistakenly copied as literal in your script. There should only be tab characters with the indentation.